# Repeating the loop from user input in C

Tags: c, gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        char n='Y';
        fflush(stdin);
        while(n=='Y')
        {
                printf("Add Next Y/N: ");
                n=getc(stdin);
        }
        printf("n = %c",n);
}
```

This loop ends after 1st iteration without taking input from keyboard.

Comment: program is not taking input for "Add Next Y/N" from keyboard after 1st iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my system, getc() does not seem to return until I hit the return key. Which means that 'Y' is always followed by '\n'. So in order to keep looping I had to add a condition to the while:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main()
{
   char n = 'Y';
   while ( toupper(n) == 'Y' || n == '\n'  )
   {
      if ( n != '\n' )
      {
         printf("Add Next Y/N: ");
      }
      n = getc(stdin);
   }
}
```

fgets() seems to work better:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main()
{
   char input[100] = { "Y" };
   while ( toupper(input[0]) == 'Y' )
   {
      printf("Add Next Y/N: ");
      fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin);
   }
}
```

Edit for comment below:
scanf() also has issues with carriage return. Better to fgets() and then sscanf(). Since you are doing the extra getchar() I think you can get rid of the check for '\n'. Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct item {
      char name[100];
      int avg;
      double cost;
};


int main()
{

   FILE *fp = fopen("getc.txt","w");
   struct item e;
   char line[200];
   char next = 'Y';
   while(toupper(next) == 'Y') 
   { 
      printf("Model name, Average, Price: "); 
      fgets(line,sizeof(line),stdin);
      sscanf(line,"%s %d %f",e.name,&e.avg,&e.cost); 
      fwrite(&e,sizeof(e),1,fp); 
      printf("Add Next (Y/N): "); 
      next = getc(stdin);
      getchar(); // to get rid of the carriage return
   }
   fclose(fp);
}
```

An alternative way without sscanf():

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct item {
      char name[100];
      int avg;
      double cost;
};
int main() 
{
   struct item e;
   char line[200];
   char next = 'Y';
   while(toupper(next) == 'Y') 
   { 
      printf("Model name ");
      fgets(line,sizeof(line),stdin);
      line[ strlen(line) - 1 ] = '\0'; // get rid of '\n'
      strcpy(e.name,line);
      printf("\nAverage "); 
      fgets(line,sizeof(line),stdin);
      e.avg = atoi(line);
      printf("\nPrice "); 
      fgets(line,sizeof(line),stdin);
      e.cost = atof(line);
      printf("you input %s %d %f\n",e.name,e.avg,e.cost);
      printf("Add Next (Y/N): "); 
      next = getc(stdin);
      getchar(); // get rid of carriage return
   }
}
```

Comment: It worked fine here. But it didn't work with the following code. e is a structure.  while(toupper(next)=='Y' || next == '\n')
                {
                        printf("Model name, Average, Price: ");
                        scanf("%s %d %f",e.name,&e.avg,&e.cost);
                        fwrite(&e,sizeof(e),1,fp);
                        if(next != '\n')
                                printf("Add Next (Y/N): ");
                        next=getc(stdin);
                        getchar();
                }

Comment: @Hello Try an fgets() and then an sscanf() as I did above.

Answer (score 3):

`fflush` is associated with output stream. Don't call it on `stdin`.

That's because after you input `Y` there's still a newline character left in the input stream which is passed to as the next input to `getc`. So now, the condition of loop failed now and comes out of the loop.

Just add a `getchar()` after the getc() to consume the newline.

Note that `getchar()` is same as `getc(stdin,ch)`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        char n='Y';

        while(n=='Y')
        {
                printf("Add Next Y/N: ");
                n=getc(stdin);
                getchar();
        }
        printf("n = %c",n);
}
```

Comment: To note it, `fflush(stdin)` is UB.

Comment: Removed fflush statement, still program is not taking input for "Add Next Y/N" from keyboard

Comment: @Hello I edited my post with the reason why it's failing and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you get input from the user (stdin from the keyboard) you're not simply getting a `Y` character, you're getting two characters: `Y\n`.

You have to either consume the `\n` or store a char array and strip it from your input, or something along those lines. Here's a quick one line fix for you that doesn't really change your code:

```
n=getc(stdin); 
getchar(); //consume the newline
```